# Update column value in all rows of a table on mod(rownum,10) = number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `tab1` that looks like this:

```
 col1 | col2 | col3
------|------|------
 abc  | 100  | text
 abc  | 100  | text
 abc  | 100  | text
 ...  | ...  | ...
```

I need to update `col2` value in each row like this:

```
update tab1 
    set col2 = 1,23
    when mod(rownum,10) = 1; 
update tab1 
    set col2 = 12,34
    when mod(rownum,10) = 2;
update tab1 
    set col2 = 123,45
    when mod(rownum,10) = 3;
```

and etc. until `when mod(rownum,10) = 9`.

But obviously this query doesn't work, and the reason is that `rownum` always returns `1` in this situation, afaik. However, I've got the correct last digits for each row number with `select mod(rownum,10) as lastDig from tab1` query. But I don't understand how to use the result of this `select` for my `update when` conditions.

Could you please provide an example of a query that will do the job in this situation? Do I need to use a subquery or `select` in a temporary table? Please explain. I'm a junior frontend guy, but I need to create a demo table this way. I believe, `pl/sql` is v10, as well as `PL/SQL Developer`.

Result wanted looks like this:

```
 col1 | col2  | col3
------|-------|------
 abc  | 1.23  | text
 abc  | 12.34 | text
 abc  | 123.45| text
 ...  | ...   | ...
```

Comment: How do you order the records? Is it just random or do you have a value to order by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CASE` expression or `DECODE`:

```
update tab1 
set col2 =  CASE mod(rownum,10) WHEN 1 THEN 1.23
                                WHEN 2 THEN 12.34
                                WHEN 3 THEN 123.45
                                -- ...
                                ELSE col2
            END
-- WHERE ...

UPDATE tab1
SET col2 = DECODE(mod(rownum,10), 1, 1.23, 2, 12.34, 3, 123.45, ..., col2)
-- WHERE ...;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=eea7a4b720053b575b4a8582371b22d9)**

Comment: So, in my case, I don't even need a `where` operator, correct? Cause it worked like a charm.

Comment: @VELFR `WHERE` is arbitrary, I put it just in case you if you want additional filtering. Feel free to skip it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have not told us if there is a specific order in which you want to treat rows as 1,2,3 .. If there is indeed an order, then `ROWNUM` is unreliable and may not work, you would need `row_number()` with a specific order by column. That can be combined with a `MERGE` statement.

```
MERGE INTO tab1 tgt USING (
    SELECT
            CASE mod( ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                ORDER BY
                    col1 -- the column which is in order and unique
            ),10)
                WHEN 1   THEN 1.23
                WHEN 2   THEN 12.34
                WHEN 3   THEN 123.45
                --..
                --.. 9
            ELSE col2
        AS col2
    FROM
        tab1 t
)
src ON ( tgt.rowid = src.rowid ) --use primary key/unique key if there is one instead of rowid
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET tgt.col2 = src.col2;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4f3e8/1)